# HAProxy tarpit timeout to be greater than client timeout

Tags: haproxy, timeout

In our situation the client timeout must be small because the long waiting clients should be disconnected, but we have an IP range of open proxies which we wan't to block with tarpit.

As our testing the tarpit timeout cannot be greater than the client timeout. How can I achieve to have a greater tarpit timeout in HAProxy than the global client timeout?

Answer (score 0):

On your tarpit session include this line

```
timeout tarpit 10s
```

Comment: I said that it cannot be greater then global client timeout, in our case the actual client timeout is `4000ms` and the tarpit is `4s` and it does not work.

Comment: After you send a connection to tarpit, the client timeout doesn´t matter, the timeout connect value is used, unless you specify the timeout tarpit value.